# Why does the hash mark in my url stop my sitemap tabs from working?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My web site is in C#.net and I use .net 2012. My site has multiple free standing pages so I decided to combine the pages that use a particular table of contents into one page of code. This is fine with the exception of my sitemap tabs will not show on the page section when called using the url  **Pages.aspx#divisions**.

The free standing page works great and shows the sitemap tabs. Am I missing something in the url, combining my code, or is this just one of MS VB's quirks?

Comment: I'm confused, is the site in both c# and vb?

Comment: Uhm, there is no .net 2012 ... did you mean Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Without knowing how your sitemap tabs are formed, this is virtually impossible to answer. Importantly, the `#divisions` is **not** ever sent to the server, so it *sounds* like possibly your client-side code is borked, in which case this is not a c# / .net / vb.net question in the first place

Comment: Here is my sitemap code:        
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="default.aspx" title="HOME">
        <siteMapNode url="divisions.aspx" title="OFFICES"/>
        <siteMapNode url="Directory.aspx" title="DIRECTORY"/>
        <siteMapNode url="wallcharts.aspx" title="CHARTS and REPORTS"/>
        <siteMapNode url="forms.aspx" title="FORMS"/>
        <siteMapNode url="HD.aspx" title="HELP DESK"/>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>